# public folder not found ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, shared-folders

I had all my code(softwares) in my Public folder. They were there until I logged in today.

I see no Public folder in Home Directory. Its really strange. Have I lost all my data?

Comment: Did you try `sudo ls /home` to check you've not lost the 'executable bit' from permissions?

Comment: @MarkWilliams executable bit has nothing to listing folders

Comment: It does if you tried listing the contents not the top directory - try it, @EdiD. It is used to set the traversability of folders, as well as executability of files..

Comment: @MarkWilliams OP doesn't see Public folder at all. If you set 000 permissions on folder it will list with `ls` command and of course can not list its contents, but you will see a folder.

Comment: You can try finding `Public` folder by its name with : `sudo find / -type d -name "Public"` maybe you accidentally move it to other location

Comment: @MarkWilliams output of `sudo ls /home` `abhimanyuaryan lost+found`

Comment: @EdiD `cd /home/abhimanyuaryan/.local/share/teamviewer11/drive_c/users` only result

Comment: You have only `~/.local` folder in your home ?

Comment: @EdiD no I have a lot of folders...Applications/Video/Music etc

Answer (score 0):

Before you write too much to the drive, you want to try a data recovery tool. This isn't going to be quick.
I would suggest you reboot the PC from a CD or USB drive, ideally plug in a large USB drive, and install 'foremost' - run this, tell it to place recovered files on the USB backup drive, run it - it's a command line tool, type `foremost` from a terminal.

This should put ALL recognised files in the USB, untitled & grouped by filetype - you can find filenames later, but at least it retrieves your hard work. It won't separate .c, .h, etc, they'll be 'text' files. It will possibly take days if your system drive was full!